# Finding Dynamically generated parameter values to be sent with http post method to login

Tags: javascript, authentication, http-post, html-parsing

I want to login to hotmail email account with httpclient. For that I need to pass 21 parameters to http post method including username and password. I found this out through temper data addon in firefox. I also found out that few of them are generated dynamically.(i.e. their values change each time we reload the page). My problem is to how do I find these dynamically generated values of the parameters which have to be passed in http post. I tried to find them with firebug addon but it did not help ! I think values are generated by javascript. If it is, then how do I parse them ? I have used Html parser before but it seems that it does not support javascript parsing. I would appreciate any idea regarding this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be some form of CSRF anti forgery token, in which case I don't think you going to come right. They might be stored in some cookie, or in a hidden element in the page.

More info: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/